Doing API calls in a hook after HTTP request has finished in SvelteKit
I have some statistics and notification API requests I'd like to do in my +server.js code.
However

These requests are statistical in nature
I do not want to block HTTP request processing
Notifications may file (likely due to rate limiting, etc.) - in this case the there should be logged on an info level, but nothing bad should happen

Thus, I'd like to run all of this after HTTP request/response cycle is completd.
Does SvelteKit have any kind of a handler that would run after the HTTP request is finished, allowing me to do some extra work like this?
Any other ideas how this could be implemented?

Use the handle server hook:
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {

    const response = await resolve(event);
    
    // Before you return here, send whichever API request you want,
    // and simply DON'T await it.
    
    return response;
    
}


The same principle (in other functions) can of course be used in +server.js files too, if you want to limit it to specific routes.
